# When return a local char array why strcpy worked but string constructor failed?

Tags: c++

Today I was met the following code block:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char *return_char_array(const char *cptr)
{
    char charArray[100] = {0};
    strcpy(charArray, cptr);
    return charArray;
}
int main()
{
    const char *cptr = "test";

    char localCharArray[100] = {0};
    strcpy(localCharArray, return_char_array(cptr)); // output "test"
    cout<<localCharArray<<endl;

    string s = return_char_array(cptr);              // corrupt output
    cout<<s<<endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

At the first sight I thought both the output would be corrupt but surprisingly the first output is "test" while the second is corrupt. Would someone tell me why?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined... Edit: In fact this doesn't even compile for me, as you give `return_char_array()` a `const char *` and you can't implicitly cast away the `const`ness. However, I guess the reason this is happening is that calling `strcpy()` doesn't put enough on the stack to overwrite that particular area of memory, whereas creating a `string` does.

Comment: @BoBTFish Sorry, I lost the `const` in the parameter list ..

Comment: Cure: `std::string` and other standard library containers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They **are** both corrupt. Just because it appears to work, doesn't mean it's ok.

This is **undefined behavior**, anything can happen, including appearing to work.